# Write output of command in bash script returns an empty file

Tags: bash, sh, stdout

I have a bash script used to write all the committers' details to a file for each repository on a list.

If I perform the steps manually, the file is written and there's content. However, if I do this using the bash script, the written file is empty (without content).

Can you help me find what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Below, you can find my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ $# -lt 1 ];then
       echo "usage: $0 <repos_list>"
       exit 1
fi

repos_list=$1

cat $repos_list | while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; 
do
    # Control will enter here if $line exists.
    if [ -d "$line" ]; then
        cd $line
        git shortlog -sne > git_commits.file 2>&1 
        echo --------------------------------
        echo "#Commits and committers for $line"
        echo --------------------------------
        cat git_commits.file
        echo --------------------------------
        rm -rf git_commits.file
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

Comment: First, note that the _or_ part of the _while_ condition will only be executed if the `read` sets an exit code, i.e. if $repos_list is exhausted. In this case, `$line` still holds the content of the last input line, but you have processed it already.  Aside from this, I guess that what is stored in `$line` is not a directory; you could verify it by adding an `else` part, where you print out: `echo Not a  directory: $line`.

Comment: An aside -Don't `cat $repos_list`. Try `done < $repos_list`.

Comment: @user1934428 The `|| [[ -n "$line" ]]` bit is for the case where the input file doesn't have a newline on the last line.

Comment: You have a `sh` shebang line, but you use bashisms such as `[[ ]]`. Use a bash shebang line instead, or use `[ ... ]` instead.

Comment: Which file do you expect to be written? The only file I see is deleted in every loop.

Comment: @BenjaminW. but I do `cat` the file before being deleted. However, it seems to be empty. if I comment the `rm` line, the file is there, but empty.

Comment: What's the output if you remove everything from inside your loop but `cd "$line"; git shortlog -sne; cd ..`?